# Using expressions in navigation property

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I can do the following in Entity Framework Core 2.0:

```
Expression<Func<MyFirstEntity, bool>> myExpression = entity => entity.SomeProperty == true;
List<MyFirstEntity> myItems = context.MyFirstEntity.Where(myExpression).ToList();
```

`MyFirstEntity` has a foreign key to `MySecondEntity`. So I can use a navigation property in `MySecondEntity`.

Example:

```
List<MySecondEntity> myItems = context.MySecondEntity
    .Where(secondEntity  => secondEntity.MyFirstEntities
         .Any(firstEntity => firstEntity.SomeProperty == true)).ToList();
```

I would like to use `myExpression` in the query. Something like this would be nice:

```
List<MySecondEntity> myItems = context.MySecondEntity
    .Where(secondEntity  => secondEntity.MyFirstEntities
         .Any(myExpression)).ToList();
```

But this gives a compile time error, because `secondEntity.MyFirstEntities` does not implement `IQueryable`. Defining a `Func<MyFirstEntity, bool>` for using in navigation properties does also not work (runtime error, because Entity Framework does not know the defined `Func`).

My current solution would be something like this:

```
List<MySecondEntity> myItems = context.MySecondEntity
    .Where(secondEntity  => context.MyFirstEntities
         .Where(firstEntity => firstEntity.SecondEntityId == secondEntity.Id)
         .Any(myExpression)).ToList();
```

This does somewhat undermine the purpose of navigation properties.

Is there a better solution?

Why are navigation properties not ´IQueryable`? They have to be transformed into SQL somehow. How does the Entity Framework do this, without expressions?

Also I noticed the resulting queries in my two working examples are different, but I so far did not notice any performance differences. Are there any?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the solution. [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit#plugging-expressions-into-entitysets--entitycollections-the-solution) to the rescue. Working example with `AsExpndable()` and `Compile()`:

```
List<MySecondEntity> myItems = context.MySecondEntity.AsExpandable()
    .Where(secondEntity  => secondEntity.MyFirstEntities
        .Any(myExpression.Compile())).ToList();
```